# Simplify Maybe monad in IO block

Tags: haskell

Say I have a function:

```
get :: String -> Maybe [(C8.ByteString, Maybe C8.ByteString)] -> IO (Response LC8.ByteString)
get url qParams' = do
  request <- parseUrl url

  --todo simplify
  let qParams = case qParams' of
                  Just p -> p
                  Nothing -> [] 

  res <- withManager $ httpLbs $ configRequest request qParams
  return res
```

I believe there is a way to simplify `let qParams = ...` expression. But I am not aware of it. I could've used 
  `Just qParams <- qParams'` if it were Maybe monad, but it is IO monad so I can't use it.

Your ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe) function:

```
let qParams = maybe [] id qParams'
```

Or as @MichaelSnoyman has suggested you can use [fromMaybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe):

```
let qParams = fromMaybe [] qParams'
```

Comment: There's also `fromMaybe`, though that requires an extra import.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `fold` from `Data.Foldable`:

```
let qParams = fold qParams'
```